# in iOS5 my methods for switching pictures in gallery are bad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I have some classes for watching pictures in gallery. in those classes after enabling ARC i get message that implicit conversion is forbidden by ARC and I cant run the application.

Those methods are:

```
- (void) curlToPrevious
{
    if (currentImageIndex == 0) return;



         if ([self.image2 superview] == NO) {

        self.image2.image = (UIImage*) [imageViews objectAtIndex:(currentImageIndex-1)];
    } else {
        self.image1.image = (UIImage*) [imageViews objectAtIndex:(currentImageIndex-1)];
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kTransitionDuration];

    currentImageIndex--;

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.containerView cache:YES];

    if ([self.image2 superview] == NO) {
        [self.image1 removeFromSuperview];
        [self.containerView addSubview:self.image2];
    } else {
        [self.image2 removeFromSuperview];
        [self.containerView addSubview:self.image1];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self updateCurrentImageCounter];
}

- (void) curlToNext
{
    if (currentImageIndex == ([self imageCount]-1)) return;

    if ([self.image2 superview] == NO) {
        self.image2.image = (UIImage*) [imageViews objectAtIndex:(currentImageIndex+1)];
    } else {
        self.image1.image = (UIImage*) [imageViews objectAtIndex:(currentImageIndex+1)];
    }
    currentImageIndex++;


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kTransitionDuration];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.containerView cache:YES];

    if ([self.image2 superview] == NO) {
        [self.image1 removeFromSuperview];
        [self.containerView addSubview:self.image2];
    } else {
        [self.image2 removeFromSuperview];
        [self.containerView addSubview:self.image1];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self updateCurrentImageCounter];
}
```

I have

```
if ([self.image2 superview] == NO) {
```

In this line on 4 places in code problem.

The text I get is:

**implicit conversion of 'int' to 'UIView' is disallowed with ARC**

How can I avoid this??? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace your code on this `if ([self.image2 superview] == nil)`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an **UIView*** with an **integer** (0) - of course you get a warning. Do you want to check whether the superview is nil? Then just do that:

`if([self.image2 superview] == nil) { ... }`